# How to get this code to work using the speech recognition engine instead of the default windows popup recognizer

Tags: c#, vb.net, speech-recognition

I am still working on my speech pronunciation test. I have this code, but I need it to use `SpeechRecognitionEngine` instead of the system popup recognizer. This bit of working code is in VB, even though I prefer to work in C#, but this has been so difficult that I will settle for whatever code or programming language that I can get. This code is totally functional, and can be tested by simply pasting into an empty VB projects, and including `Import System.Speech.Recognition`. Can someone show me how to make this code use the SpeechEngine with the .

I can discuss setting the default audio input and getting rid of the recognizer start code, it of course must be removed. But, to keep things simple, I have left the code as is for live testing. Thanks

```
Imports System.Speech.Recognition

Imports System.Threading

Imports System.Globalization

Public Class Form1

    ' recogniser & grammar
    Dim recog As New SpeechRecognizer
    Dim gram As Grammar
    ' events
    Public Event SpeechRecognized As _
        EventHandler(Of SpeechRecognizedEventArgs)
    Public Event SpeechRecognitionRejected As _
        EventHandler(Of SpeechRecognitionRejectedEventArgs)
    ' word list
    Dim wordlist As String() = New String() {"Yes", "No", "Maybe"}
    ' word recognised event
    Public Sub recevent(ByVal sender As System.Object,
            ByVal e As RecognitionEventArgs)
        LabelYes.ForeColor = Color.LightGray
        LabelNo.ForeColor = Color.LightGray
        LabelMaybe.ForeColor = Color.LightGray
        If (e.Result.Text = "Yes") Then
            LabelYes.ForeColor = Color.Green
        ElseIf (e.Result.Text = "No") Then
            LabelNo.ForeColor = Color.Green
        ElseIf (e.Result.Text = "Maybe") Then
            LabelMaybe.ForeColor = Color.Green
        End If
    End Sub
    ' recognition failed event
    Public Sub recfailevent(ByVal sender As System.Object,
            ByVal e As RecognitionEventArgs)
        LabelYes.ForeColor = Color.LightGray
        LabelNo.ForeColor = Color.LightGray
        LabelMaybe.ForeColor = Color.LightGray
    End Sub
    ' form initialisation
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object,
            ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' need these to get British English rather than default US
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("en-GB")
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("en-GB")
        ' convert the word list into a grammar
        Dim words As New Choices(wordlist)
        gram = New Grammar(New GrammarBuilder(words))
        recog.LoadGrammar(gram)
        ' add handlers for the recognition events
        AddHandler recog.SpeechRecognized, AddressOf Me.recevent
        AddHandler recog.SpeechRecognitionRejected, AddressOf Me.recfailevent
        ' enable the recogniser
        recog.Enabled = True
    End Sub
End Class
```